# PTIJ: The Tooth Fairy and theft

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As the child who puts his or her tooth under the pillow does not have the halachic standing to make anything hefker, the tooth remains his or hers so anyone taking it should be held accountable for theft.

Would the [tooth fairy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59800/is-there-anything-wrong-with-the-tooth-fairy) then be liable for repeated counts of גזל שנה?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

A child may not "have the halachic standing to make anything hefker", but neither does he have the halachic standing to own anything.  So either the father says "Hefker!" or he hides until the tooth fairy shows up and drags her before the bet din.

Comment: Can magical, non-human entities be put on trial?

Comment: I think your claim that "neither does he have the halachic standing to own anything" is not entirely accurate. See for example [Sukkah 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.46b?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) which brings down the idea that a child can acquire something but not give it away.

Comment: @harel13 I believe the Baal Shem tov put a shaid under trial once

Answer (score 1):

A close reading of the teaching אין אדם מקנה דבר שלא בא לעולם, *a man may not transfer acquisition to someone who has not come into the world*, seems to indicate that it is specifically an adult which can arrange transactions with imaginary beings. Children should be a-okay.